# Как сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии кнопки поток не запускался повторно?

Tags: android

В Activity при регистрации в потоке посылается POST-запрос на сервер. Если пользователь удачно зарегестрировался то приходит код 200 и должен произойти переход на следующую Activity. Если сразу нажать кнопку повторно, запрос происходит второй раз и возвращается код ошибки 404, так как пользователь уже зарегистрировался, но не успевает осуществиться переход на следующую Activity.  Как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии кнопки не запускался заново этот же поток пока он не выполнится(или не выполнится блок кода с переходом)?

```
public class Password extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnDone;
    EditText etNewPassword;
    public static RequestInterface requestInterface;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);

        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        etNewPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_new_password);

        btnDone.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnDone:         
                    requestInterface = Controller.getApi();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
                    String newPassword = etNewPassword.getText().toString();
                    JsonObject createdJson = new JsonObject();
                    createdJson.addProperty("email", email);
                    createdJson.addProperty("password", newPassword);

                    requestInterface.registerUser(createdJson).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                            if(response.code() == 200) {
                                Intent newIntent = new Intent(Password.this, ShopLenta.class);
                                startActivity(newIntent);
                            } 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });

                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После первого нажатия по кнопке, можно сразу же ей установить свойство

> btnDone.setClickable(false)

и кнопка просто не будет кликабельна